# Theano and Celery : Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: segmentation-fault, celery, theano

I'm building a web app where I start the training of a neural network implemented with theano on the server side by sending an ajax request from the client. Obviously I don't want to wait for the server to train the network entirely to send an answer back to my client because it would be way to long.

So I came up with celery which enable me to do asynchronous code on the server side. I run the celery workers with the command `celery -A CBIR worker -l info`. Unfortunately I get the following message each time a worker is running my task (which is training my network using theano) :

```
[2015-12-14 19:15:06,790: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-3' pid:1610 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2015-12-14 19:15:07,001: ERROR/MainProcess] Task fit[ac40d4d4-5b56-4278-b270-647ef76f3a49] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/leo/anaconda/envs/ImgRet/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1175, in mark_as_worker_losthuman_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

I have been searching why this error might occur and from what I understand the code I'm running is suffering memory leak. What I don't understand is why my code has no problem running when not using celery but this error come up when using Celery ?

And most importantly I have no clue how to resolve this. I used lldb to look at the dump file generated and here is the backtrace I have :

```
thread #1: tid = 0x0000, 0x00007fff93b4a9b3 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_group_async + 533, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
* frame #0: 0x00007fff93b4a9b3 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_group_async + 533
frame #1: 0x00007fff7c5b8d40 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queues + 1280
frame #2: 0x00007fff9519b228 libBLAS.dylib`APL_dgemm + 1100
frame #3: 0x00007fff951d27aa libBLAS.dylib`cblas_dgemm + 1420
frame #4: 0x0000000104beeb18 multiarray.cpython-35m-darwin.so`gemm + 200
frame #5: 0x0000000104bee3b9 multiarray.cpython-35m-darwin.so`cblas_matrixproduct + 3097
frame #6: 0x0000000104bc01af multiarray.cpython-35m-darwin.so`PyArray_MatrixProduct2 + 207
frame #7: 0x0000000104bc4808 multiarray.cpython-35m-darwin.so`array_matrixproduct + 264
frame #8: 0x00000001000671a9 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyCFunction_Call + 281
frame #9: 0x00000001000f2fbd libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32029
frame #10: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #11: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #12: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #13: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #14: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #15: 0x00000001000e95a7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87
frame #16: 0x00000001042fae3a lazylinker_ext.so`pycall(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, node_idx=13, verbose=0) + 442 at mod.cpp:510
frame #17: 0x00000001042fa869 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=24, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 2089 at mod.cpp:704
frame #18: 0x00000001042fa789 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=28, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 1865 at mod.cpp:690
frame #19: 0x00000001042fa16d lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=30, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 301 at mod.cpp:576
frame #20: 0x00000001042fa789 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=33, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 1865 at mod.cpp:690
frame #21: 0x00000001042fa789 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=36, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 1865 at mod.cpp:690
frame #22: 0x00000001042fa789 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=41, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 1865 at mod.cpp:690
frame #23: 0x00000001042fa789 lazylinker_ext.so`lazy_rec_eval(self=0x0000000108fad3d8, var_idx=42, one=0x000000010026cf60, zero=0x000000010026cf40) + 1865 at mod.cpp:690
frame #24: 0x00000001042f83db lazylinker_ext.so`CLazyLinker_call(_self=0x0000000108fad3d8, args=0x0000000100382048, kwds=0x0000000000000000) + 811 at mod.cpp:838
frame #25: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #26: 0x00000001000ed08c libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7660
frame #27: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #28: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #29: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #30: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #31: 0x000000010002a79c libpython3.5m.dylib`method_call + 140
frame #32: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #33: 0x0000000100080743 libpython3.5m.dylib`slot_tp_call + 67
frame #34: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #35: 0x00000001000ed08c libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7660
frame #36: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #37: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #38: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #39: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #40: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #41: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #42: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #43: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #44: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #45: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #46: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #47: 0x000000010002a79c libpython3.5m.dylib`method_call + 140
frame #48: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #49: 0x0000000100080743 libpython3.5m.dylib`slot_tp_call + 67
frame #50: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #51: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #52: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #53: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #54: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #55: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #56: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #57: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #58: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #59: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #60: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #61: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #62: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #63: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #64: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #65: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #66: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #67: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #68: 0x000000010002a79c libpython3.5m.dylib`method_call + 140
frame #69: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #70: 0x0000000100080471 libpython3.5m.dylib`slot_tp_init + 81
frame #71: 0x000000010007b114 libpython3.5m.dylib`type_call + 212
frame #72: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #73: 0x00000001000ed08c libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7660
frame #74: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #75: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #76: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #77: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #78: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #79: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #80: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #81: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #82: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #83: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #84: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #85: 0x000000010002a79c libpython3.5m.dylib`method_call + 140
frame #86: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #87: 0x0000000100080471 libpython3.5m.dylib`slot_tp_init + 81
frame #88: 0x000000010007b114 libpython3.5m.dylib`type_call + 212
frame #89: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #90: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #91: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #92: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #93: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #94: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #95: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #96: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #97: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #98: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #99: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #100: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #101: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #102: 0x00000001000f4ef7 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 71
frame #103: 0x0000000100041d2a libpython3.5m.dylib`function_call + 186
frame #104: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #105: 0x000000010002a79c libpython3.5m.dylib`method_call + 140
frame #106: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #107: 0x0000000100080743 libpython3.5m.dylib`slot_tp_call + 67
frame #108: 0x000000010000d783 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyObject_Call + 99
frame #109: 0x00000001000eff0b libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19563
frame #110: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #111: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #112: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #113: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #114: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #115: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #116: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #117: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #118: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #119: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #120: 0x00000001000f3d26 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 35462
frame #121: 0x00000001000f4053 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 36275
frame #122: 0x00000001000f4df0 libpython3.5m.dylib`_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2400
frame #123: 0x00000001000f4f51 libpython3.5m.dylib`PyEval_EvalCode + 81
frame #124: 0x0000000100123d4e libpython3.5m.dylib`PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
frame #125: 0x0000000100123fef libpython3.5m.dylib`PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
frame #126: 0x000000010013c7d7 libpython3.5m.dylib`Py_Main + 3479
frame #127: 0x0000000100000e92 python3`main + 418
frame #128: 0x0000000100000cc4 python3`start + 52
```

I don't really know how to interpret this backtrace. Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: is the core dump available? have you run gdb on it?

Comment: I'm trying to use gdb but I think i'm missing something.  What I have done is run the worker `python manage.py celery worker` and then I do `gdb python <pid>` and enter c in the gdb shell. But after that my gdb shell display Continuing and I cannot entre any command any more. And when my worker exit whit the segfault it does not display anything.

Comment: no - there should be a core dump on your system after the segfault - it's going to be easier to analyse that. check the value of `ulimit -c` and of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`

Comment: I edited my post with the backtrace from the core dump. I hope it's what you meant. First time I use core dump.

Comment: ah - you're running under python 3. i'm not familiar with this. how do you run the celery workers? can you include the full command line you use?

Comment: I included the command line in the question

Comment: python3/OSX... probably not the most common combination. Something odd is going on - celery log report SIGSEGV, but the coredump report SIGSTOP - I don't really know much about OSX - maybe somehow this can happen - on Linux, certainly, this would be plain weird. I'd suggest opening a bug in the celery [bugtracker](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues)

Answer (score 5):

If anyone run into the same problem turns out a workaround is to import theano library inline in the task and not at the module level.

This way :

```
import baz
import bar

@app.task
def foo():
    import theano

    # do something with theano
```

Check [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2964#issuecomment-165669659) for more explanation

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this also happens with `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`.  Works fine if I create threads on my own using `threading.Thread`.  Gets a sig11 if I attempt to call `fit` under Celery workers.

I've not had the same issues with `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, `Ridge` or `LinearRegression`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's a comment/new question. Once you have sufficient reputation (50) you will be able to comment on any post. In the meantime you can gain reputation by asking your own questions or providing answers on subjects you know.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed all packages imported at the top of the tasks.py file except importing app from .celery `from <project>.celery import app`, and then import packages within the individual task functions. And it worked.